# how to access vairables outside of map function in js and jsx in a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
var PieceList = React.createClass({

  render: function() {

    var pieces;
    if (this.props.pieces && this.props.onDeletePiece2) {
      var pieces = this.props.pieces.map(function (piece) {
        return (
          <Piece pieceData={piece} onDeletePiece3={this.props.onDeletePiece2} />
        )
      });
    }
    return (
      <div className="piecesTable">
        {pieces}
      </div>
    );  
  }
});
```

I'm stumped as to how to get this to work. The problem is that {this.props} is not available inside of the map function.

Would a foreach be better here?  stumped, pls halp!

Answer (score 19):

`map` is just a regular JavaScript method (see [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)). It can take an argument that sets the context (`.map(callback[, thisArg])`):

```
var PieceList = React.createClass({

  render: function() {

    var pieces;
    if (this.props.pieces && this.props.onDeletePiece2) {
      var pieces = this.props.pieces.map(function (piece) {
        return (
          <Piece pieceData={piece} onDeletePiece3={this.props.onDeletePiece2} />
        )
      }, this); // need to add the context
    }
    return (
      <div className="piecesTable">
        {pieces}
      </div>
    );  
  }
});
```

I would suggest going back and reading about `this` in JavaScript. When you pass an anonymous function to most methods (like `.map`, `.forEach`, etc.), it takes the global context (which is almost always `window`). If you pass in `this` as the last argument, since that `this` is referring to the class you just created with `React.createClass`, it'll set the correct context.

In other words, the way you were trying to do it was access `window.props`, which obviously doesn't exist. I'd if you opened your console to debug, you'd see the error `Object Window doesn't have the property "props"` or something very obfuscated.

Comment: thanks so much. i'm newer to JS and frontend stuff, but i will study up on this. thanks!

Comment: i got You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototype and I'm half way through- really needed that.  Also this was the only solution that worked out of the box and was dead simple. +1 thanks!

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT 2: React 0.14.x**

You can now define [stateless functional components](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#stateless-functional-components) for components that do not require complex lifecycle event hooks or internal state

```
const PieceList = ({pieces, onDeletePiece2}) => {
  if (!onDeletePiece2) return;
  return (
    <div className="piecesTable">
      {pieces.map(x => (
        <Pieces pieceData={x} onDeletePiece3={onDeletePiece2}>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

---

**EDIT 1: ES6**

As ES6 continues to become more prominent, you can also avoid nitpicky context issues by using an ES6 [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```
class PieceList extends React.Component {
  renderPiece(piece) {
    return <Piece pieceData={piece} onDeletePiece3={this.props.onDeletePiece2} />;
  }
  render() {
    if (!this.props.onDeletePiece2) return;
    return (
      <div className="piecesTable">
        {this.props.pieces.map(piece => this.renderPiece(piece))}
      <div>
    );
  }
}
```

To get this to run in most environments, you'd need to "transpile" it using something like [babel.js](http://babeljs.io/)

---

The quick answer is that you need to bind the proper `this` to the `map` callback by passing `this` as the second arg

```
this.props.pieces.map(..., this);
```

This might be a better way to write your component tho

```
var PieceList = React.createClass({

  renderPiece: function(piece) {
    return <Piece pieceData={piece} onDeletePiece3={this.props.onDeletePiece2} />;
  },

  render: function() {
    if (!this.props.onDeletePiece2) return;
    return (
      <div className="piecesTable">
        {this.props.pieces.map(this.renderPiece, this)}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Regarding your comment about `map`

```
var x = {a: 1, b: 2};

['a', 'b'].map(function(key) {
  // `this` is set to `x`
  // `key` will be `'a'` for the first iteration
  // `key` will be `'b'` for the second iteration
  console.log(this[key]);
}, x); // notice we're passing `x` as the second argument to `map`
```

Will output

```
// "1"
// "2"
```

Notice how the second argument to `map` can set the context for the function. When you call `this` inside the function, it will be equal to the second variable that was sent to `map`.

This is JavaScript basics and you should definitely read up more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: thanks. hmmmmm, i kind of follow, but not all the way, can you please elaborate?

Comment: interesting way to structure a component, thanks for sharing.  I'm still not sure I understand how the the this.props would be available in the map function- but i need to dig deeper into javascript as its not my main language. can i just cut/paste your example to get my bit of code to work? thanks

Comment: Thanks for such a well thought out answer with links included, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a transpiler -- something like Babel? If so, this code will work fine:

```
if (this.props.pieces && this.props.onDeletePiece2) {
  var pieces = this.props.pieces.map((piece, i) => {
    return (
      <Piece pieceData={piece} onDeletePiece3={this.props.onDeletePiece2} key={i}/>
    )
  });
  ...
```

If you can't use a transpiler, you could do this:

```
if (this.props.pieces && this.props.onDeletePiece2) {  
var that = this;
    var pieces = that.props.pieces.map( function(piece, i) {
    return (
      <Piece pieceData={piece} onDeletePiece3={that.props.onDeletePiece2} key={i}/>
    )
  })
```

...